# How do I find the general term for the following recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

$a_{n+1} = -\frac{5a_n}{2n+1}$  for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$

Ex. For $a_1 = 1$

$a_2 = -\frac{5}{3}$

$a_3 = \frac{5}{3}$

$a_4 = -\frac{25}{21}$

$a_5 = \frac{125}{189}$

$a_6 = -\frac{625}{2079}$

etc.

Thank you

Comment: HINT : The numerators are power of $5$ and the denominators are of the form $3, 3\cdot 5, 3\cdot 5\cdot 7,...$. Try to adapt that to your formula and prove by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to expand explicitly a few terms :
$$
a_n = \frac{-5}{2n-1} a_{n-1} =  \frac{-5}{2n-1} \frac{-5}{2n-3} a_{n-2} = \frac{-5}{2n-1} \frac{-5}{2n-3} \frac{-5}{2n-5} a_{n-3}
$$
So it is rather clear that the numerator will be of the form $5^k$ and the denominator of the form "$1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$". Also note that because of the minus sign, the sign of the sequence will flip every time. So we will also have a factor of the form $(-1)^k$.
Now let's observe a bit the first few terms :
$$
a_1 = 1 \\
a_2 = \frac{-5}{3} \\
a_3 = \frac{25}{3 \cdot 5} \\
a_4 = \frac{-125}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}
$$
We can conjecture that $$a_n = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{5^{n-1}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (2i+1)}$$
(Where the empty product is defined to be $1$ when $n=1$)

Comment: You can start the product at $i=0$ and not have to worry about an empty product. It may also be worth pointing out that the denominator is $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, so that the whole thing can be written $$\frac{2(-10)^{n-1}n!}{(2n)!}\;.$$